How can I show the camera stream of my Tello drone with OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi 5?
I can't open a picture with OpenCV if i use the Djitellopy library.
I want to display the live cam of my Tello with OpenCV, but it only shows errors. I use a Raspberry Pi 5.
So I tried a test function just for openCV to see if everything works correctly with cv2.
So my test code is:
import cv2

def main(args):
    image = cv2.imread('testcv2.png')
    if image is None:
        print("pic wrong")
        return
    cv2.imshow("Test", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))

With this code my picture normally opens with OpenCV.
But if i add:
from djitellopy import Tello 

At the beginning, the code runs without an error but OpenCV does not open the picture again.
I tried changing the hierarchy of the 'imports' and used the github of the djitellopy lib, but nobody has the same problem. On my normal Laptop there isn't this error, so I think it's bcs of the RasPi.
